# About the definition of stein manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

There's an equivalent characterization for stein manifold:

A complex manifold is $\textbf{Stein}$ if and only if it embeds into some $\mathbb{C}^N$ as a closed complex submanifold.( refer to Hormander's standard textbook e.g.)

However,as well known,the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^m$ is a stein manifold .So,The two facts are contradictory,the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^m$ cannot be a closed submanifold of some $\mathbb{C}^N$.

I want to know, what's wrong?

Comment: I think a closed (compact no boundary) complex manifold is Stein if there is closed embedding from it to $\mathbb{C}^n$. The unit ball is not closed so there is no contradiction.

Comment: @IEm  ,every open subset of $ \mathbb C^n$ is complex submanifold of $ \mathbb C^n$ ,however ,only  a domain of  holomorphy in $ \mathbb C^n$ is a stein manifold.

Comment: @jacklion I think Hormander studies a special class of stein manifold, and you are right, there are stein manifold that are open. The most general definition can be found here: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Stein_space

Answer (score 2):

The two facts are not contradictory. Unit ball in $ \mathbb{C}^m $ can be properly embedded into $\mathbb{C}^{2m+1}$ by the theorem 5.3.9 in Hormander's book even though it is open in $ \mathbb{C}^m $.